# Javascript event which occurs when resizing a DOM element?

Tags: javascript, html, window-resize, resizable

Im working on a project in which the height value of a resizable div always needs to be divisible by 24 (This is so it always matches the default lineheight). I have created a function for resizing the div and i now need to run the function whenever the div is resized. Events that fire when the entire window is resized exist but im not able to find any events which fire when a specific DOM element is resized.

The following is my code:

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div id="resizable-div" onresize="changeHeight()"></div>
<body>
```

**Javascript**

```
let resizeDiv = document.getElementById('resizable-div');

function changeHeight(){

  if (resizeDiv.style.height % 24 != 0) {
    resizeDiv.style.height = `${Math.round(resizeDiv.offsetHeight / 24) * 24}px`
  }
    
}
```

I was expecting the above code to change the height of `resizable-div` whenever it was resized. It doesn't, however when writing my code like this:

```
<body onresize="changeHeight()">
    <div id="resizable-div"></div>
<body>
```

It produces the outcome im looking for, but only whenever the size of the entire viewport is changed. How can i call my function whenever the height of my `resizable-div` changes?

Comment: After looking around a bit more i found the ResizeObserver API and i added this to my javascript code:
`const observer = new ResizeObserver(entries => {
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    changeHeight();
  });
});`

`observer.observe(resizeDiv);`

This creates a snapping like effect which is what im looking for but it produces really unreliable outcomes which don't land on a number divisble by 24.

Comment: Remove this if `if (resizeDiv.style.height % 24 != 0) {` and should work with the observer

Comment: @Konrad Still produces some wonky height results. But adding an eventlistener for 'mouseup' worked fine for what im trying to do. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After deciding to use my brain the solution was painfully simple. Since the div is resized by the user dragging it, i can simply add an event listener to the `resizable-div` which listens to the `mouseup` event. Here is the code:

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div id="resizable-div"></div>
<body>
```

**Javascript**

```
let resizeDiv = document.getElementById('resizable-div');

function changeHeight(){
  if (resizeDiv.offsetHeight % 24 != 0) {
      resizeDiv.style.height = `${Math.round(resizeDiv.offsetHeight / 24) * 24}px`
  }
}

resizeDiv.addEventListener('mouseup', (event) => {
  changeHeight();
})
```

This will make the div snap to the closest height that is divisible by 24 whenever the user stops dragging it.